# Looking for a better way to attach reflection methods with objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reflection

I'm looking for a fast and clean way to attach a couple of reflection methods on objects located inside an array, but I don't want to monkey-patch the objects. The objects themselves may be of varying sizes as they're returned from a dynamic JSON endpoint, thus not going down the route of `ObjWrapper(obj) { this.foo = obj.foo; }`.

I've come up with the following code, but I do feel there would be a more elegant way to achieve the same result. I would be happy to explore the use of `Lodash`'s functions:

```
var objs = [{foo:'bar'}, {foo:'baz'}];

function ObjWrapper(obj){
  var self = this;
  // Inherit all the shallow object properties
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
    self[key] = obj[key];
  });
}

ObjWrapper.prototype.isBar = function() {
  return this.foo === 'bar';
}

ObjWrapper.prototype.isBaz = function() {
  return this.foo === 'baz';
}

objsWrapped = objs.map(function(obj){
  return new ObjWrapper(obj);
});

objsWrapped.forEach(function(objWrapped){
  console.log(objWrapped.isBar());
  console.log(objWrapped.isBaz()); 
});
```

I'm not seeing a performance difference in this approach over using a static function to evaluate the object logic: http://jsperf.com/object-wrapping

For clarity, the question is; can this be written better?

Comment: weird.. i run jspref and the results claim that the helper functions are WAY better then the obj instance. however i recommend this link that covers the subject in-depth: http://blog.soulserv.net/understanding-object-cloning-in-javascript-part-i/

Comment: Never use `console.log` in your benchmark tests. And always try to narrow the tests as much as possible, for instance, `forEach` in that case could also be replaced with simple loop. And yeah, the helper functions are much more performance http://jsperf.com/object-wrapping/2

Answer (score 2):

First of all to your approach, though it is not quite a bad solution, but in a `ObjWrapper` constructor you modifes the `ObjWrapper`s hidden class, and you will become the performance penalties.  [More about hidden classes](https://developers.google.com/v8/design#fast-property-access).

Some options you have.

1. As you have already mentioned, monky-patch original objects.
2. Create a proxy object

   ```
   function ObjProxy(obj) {
       this.data = obj;
   }
   ObjProxy.prototype = {
       isFoo () {
           return this.data.foo === 'foo';
       }
   }
   ```
3. Merge two objects. Similar to your solution, but now we work with raw objects

   ```
   var Methods = {
       isFoo () {
           return this.foo === 'foo'
       }
   };
   var obj = {foo: 'foo'};
   var objWrapper = Object.assign({}, obj, Methods);
   ```
4. Functions: Utility methods are also a good solution, as you can use them as filters.

   ```
   function isFoo(obj) {
       return obj.foo === 'foo';
   }
   // Or as an utility object
   var Methods = {
       isBar (obj) {
           return obj.foo === 'bar';
       }
   }

   objs.filter(isFoo).filter(Methods.isBar);
   ```

Fourth option has the best performance, und I think will suite here the most.

Comment: thanks for these suggestions, I already knew about these alternatives but they all have some drawbacks. 

Method 2. means you have to work with the proxy container or a getter to the original object. Let's imagine I had car:{color:"red"}, to get access after it's wrapped: car.data.color, bit ugly.

Method 3. This is close to what I was looking for and wasn't aware of Object.assign :) Problem is it destroys previous proto chain.

Method 4. I'm currently leaning towards this. I included this in my JS perf as it's the "best practice".

Comment: Note that `Object.assign` is quite [new](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Object_static_methods_Object.assign), and your should include some polyfills. And what do you mean with `it destroyes proto chain`, of which object?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to replace this implementation:

```
ObjWrapper.prototype.isBar = function() 
{
     return this.foo === 'bar';
}
```

with this one:

```
ObjWrapper.prototype.isType = function(type) 
{
     return this.foo === type;
}
```

then just call:

```
console.log(objWrapped.isType('bar'));
```

the parameter itself ('bar') can be replaced with any variable

Comment: these were just meta examples of multiple methods being attached so this optimization would be missing the core question.

Comment: can you describe the final usage you intend to get in the original question?

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, I've added a bit more detail. I've just got a feeling I'm doing something wrong or missing a JS shortcut.